# node-cron only working with an active session

Tags: node.js, server, node-cron

I have a simple `node-cron` schedule that calls a function:

```js
cron.schedule('00 00 00 * * *', () => {
  console.log('update movies', new Date().toISOString());
  updateMovies();
});
```

When I log in to my server using PuTTy or use the droplet console in Digital Ocean and then run the `updateMovies.mjs` file `node server/updateMovies.mjs` and wait for the time that the cron-job should run, everything works as expected.

But when I close PuTTy or the droplet console in Digital Ocean, then nothing happens when the cron-job should run. So the server seems to lose the cron-job when I close the session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Short answer

You need to run the app in the background

```
nohup node server/updateMovies.mjs >/dev/null 2>&1
```

#### Long answer

Run your app directly in the shell is just for demos or academic purposes. On an enterprise environment you should a live process like a server which runs independently of the shell user.

##### Foreground and background processes

- Processes that require a user to start them or to interact with them are called **foreground processes**
- Processes that are run independently of a user are referred to as **background processes**.

##### How run background process (Linux)

No body uses windows for an modern deployments, so in Linux the usual strategy is to use **nohup**

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.type('text/plain');
  res.send('Hell , its about time!!');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

```
nohup node server.js >/dev/null 2>&1
```

If you  login to the server using some shell client, and run only `node server.js` it will start but if you close the shell window, the process will ends.

[image]

##### How run background process with nodejs and PM2

```
pm2 server.js
```

More details here:

https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/

#### Best way : Docker

You need to dockerize your app and it will run everywhere with this command:

```
docker run -d my_app_nodejs ....
```

Comment: `nohup` didn't seem to do much but `pm2` works great. Even comes with a nice little webbased tool to view all the active apps.

Comment: nohup is used on server bash automations in which nodejs or anothers languages are an option